# how to group all toast notifications from one app in windows 10 action center

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone, win-universal-app, toast, wns

In window universal apps, using WNS(windows notification service) is there any way to group all toast notifications sent from one app inside the action center just like how all unread whatsapp conversations are shown as one notification in Android.

I see there is a WNS header called WNS-Group and WNS-Tag but setting/using those in anyway does not group the toasts

Can someone suggest if this is doable in Windows, if it is how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't visually group notifications together (yet). The group and tag headers are to allow you to manage (e.g. dismiss) notifications together as a group.